# Getting pending suggested edit notification of my own tag wiki edits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, top-bar

As a [10K+ user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) I get notification about pending suggested edit at the top bar. I can directly edit questions and answers. But as a less 20K reputation user I have to suggest edits for tag wiki and excerpt. I just suggested edits for [comment-editing](/questions/tagged/comment-editing). After suggesting edits, I got two pending suggested edits notification. So I clicked on it go review it. And I got this:

> [image]

So I went to [the review page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review) to confirm whether there is actual pending edits or not and I got this:

> [image]

But there were no pending suggested edits. But the top bar were still showing two pending edits.

So remove the notification for my own pending suggested edits for tag wiki from the top bar (same as the review page.)

Comment: By notification I mean [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LDCMP.png). Don't know the actual word.